# Is creating subclasses for specific instances a bad practice?

Tags: programming-practices, inheritance, class-design, anti-patterns

Consider the following design

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual string Name { get; }

    public Person (string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class Karl : Person
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Karl";
        }
    }
}

public class John : Person
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "John";
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think there is something wrong here? To me Karl and John classes should be just instances instead of classes as they are exactly the same as :

```
Person karl = new Person("Karl");
Person john = new Person("John");
```

Why would I create new classes when instances are enough? The classes does not add anything to the instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will find this in lots of production code. Clean it up when you can.

Comment: This is a great design - if a developer wants to make himself indispensable for every change in business data, and has no problems to be available 24/7 ;-)

Comment: Here's a sort of related question where the OP seems to believe the opposite of conventional wisdom. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/253612/one-boilerplate-class-or-many-similar-classes

Comment: Off-hand, I can't think of a good reason to do this, but if I could, this is still probably the wrong way to do it -- have the parameterless constructor of Karl, call the single parameter constructor for person.  Have the single parameter constructor for Karl check to see if name = "Karl". Karl is guaranteeing that it is a specific instance of Person, that should be reflected in the code, not just incidentally in the output.

Comment: Design your classes depending on behavior not data. To me the sub-classes add no new behavior to the hierarchy.

Comment: This is widely used with anonymous subclasses (such as event handlers) in Java before lambdas came to Java 8 (which is the same thing with different syntax).

Comment: Maybe there was some behavior that was expected to be added to the sub classes that never made it into the code base yet, or is about to be added some someone elses next checkin.

Comment: Take note you can't use this technique with variable data e.g. `Person person = new Person(textbox1.Text)` vs ... what? `Textbox1_Text textbox1_Text = new Textbox1_Text();`

Comment: Don't overuse inheritance. Usually you won't need inheritance. Inheritance is one of the strongest means of coupling which means an inflexible solution. Prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There is no need to have specific subclasses for every person.

You're right, those should be instances instead.

### Goal of subclasses: to extend parent classes

Subclasses are used to **extend the functionality** provided by the parent class. For example, you may have:

- A parent class `Battery` which can `Power()` something and can have a `Voltage` property,
- And a subclass `RechargeableBattery`, which can inherits `Power()` and `Voltage`, but can also be `Recharge()`d.

Notice that you can pass an instance of `RechargeableBattery` class as a parameter to any method which accepts a `Battery` as an argument. This is called **[Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))**, one of the five SOLID principles. Similarly, in real life, if my MP3 player accepts two AA batteries, I can substitute them by two rechargeable AA batteries.

Note that it is sometimes difficult to determine whether you need to use a field or a subclass to represent a difference between something. For example, if you have to handle AA, AAA and 9-Volt batteries, would you create three subclasses or use an enum? “Replace Subclass with Fields” in [*Refactoring*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201485672) by Martin Fowler, page 232, may give you some ideas and how to move from one to another.

In your example, `Karl` and `John` don't extend anything, nor do they provide any additional value: you can have the exactly same functionality using `Person` class directly. **Having more lines of code with no additional value is never good.**

### An example of a business case

What could possibly be a business case where it would actually make sense to create a subclass for a specific person?

Let's say we build an application which manages persons working in a company. The application manages permissions too, so Helen, the accountant, cannot access SVN repository, but Thomas and Mary, two programmers, cannot access accounting-related documents.

Jimmy, the big boss (founder and CEO of the company) have very specific privileges no one has. He can, for example, shut down the entire system, or fire a person. You get the idea.

The poorest model for such application is to have classes such as:

[image: The class diagram shows Helen, Thomas, Mary and Jimmy classes and their common parent: the abstract Person class.]

because code duplication will arise very quickly. Even in the very basic example of four employees, you will duplicate code between Thomas and Mary classes. This will push you to create a common parent class `Programmer`. Since you may have multiple accountants as well, you will probably create `Accountant` class as well.

[image: The class diagram shows an abstract Person with three children: abstract Accountant, an abstract Programmer, and Jimmy. Accountant has a subclass Helen, and Programmer has two subclasses: Thomas and Mary.]

Now, you notice that having the class `Helen` is not very useful, as well as keeping `Thomas` and `Mary`: most of your code works at the upper level anyway—at the level of accountants, programmers and Jimmy. The SVN server doesn't care if it's Thomas or Mary who needs to access the log—it only needs to know whether it's a programmer or an accountant.

```cs
if (person is Programmer)
{
    this.AccessGranted = true;
}
```

So you end up removing the classes you don't use:

[image: The class diagram contains Accountant, Programmer and Jimmy subclasses with its common parent class: abstract Person.]

“But I can keep Jimmy as-is, since there would always be only one CEO, one big boss—Jimmy”, you think. Moreover, Jimmy is used a lot in your code, which actually looks more like this, and not as in the previous example:

```cs
if (person is Jimmy)
{
    this.GiveUnrestrictedAccess(); // Because Jimmy should do whatever he wants.
}
else if (person is Programmer)
{
    this.AccessGranted = true;
}
```

The problem with that approach is that Jimmy can still be hit by a bus, and there would be a new CEO. Or the board of directors may decide that Mary is so great that she should be a new CEO, and Jimmy would be demoted to a position of a salesperson, so now, you need to walk through *all* your code and change everything.

Comment: @DocBrown: I'm often surprised to see that short answers which are not wrong but not deep enough have a much higher score than answers which explain in depth the subject. Probably too many people don't like to read a lot, so very short answers look more attractive to them. Still, I edited my answer to provide at least some explanation.

Comment: Short answers tend to be posted first. Earlier posts get more up votes.

Comment: @TimB: I usually start with medium-sized answers, and then edit them to be very complete (here's [an example](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/257091/revisions), given that there was probably around fifteen revisions, only four being shown). I noticed that the longer becomes the answer over time, the less upvotes it receives; a similar question which remains short attracts more upvotes.

Comment: Agree with @DocBrown.  For example, a good answer would say something like "subclass for *behavior*, not for content", and refer to some reference that I won't do in this comment.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the last paragraph: Even if you only have 1 person with unrestricted access, you should still make that person be an instance of a separate class that implements unrestricted access. Checking for the person itself results in code-data interaction and can open up a whole can of worms. For example, what if the Board of Directors decides to appoint a triumvirate as CEO? If you didn't have a class "Unrestricted", you wouldn't just have to update the existing CEO, but also add 2 more checks for the other members. If you did have it, you just set them as "Unrestricted".

Comment: Instead of having an if-else on the type, wouldn't they each just have their own behavior method to be called?

Comment: +1 Really nice spiffing up of a simple answer into a pretty awesome one!

Comment: +1 You explain things so well, and your examples are perfect.  Nice.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: When practical, one should allow for the possibility of multiple instances, but it's important to affirmatively decide whether there can be multiple instances or not.  In many cases, the existence of multiple instances may necessitate additional business rules.  For example, if there can only be one administrative user logged in at a time, no business rule is required to handle simultaneous conflicting requests by different administrators because such requests cannot occur.  Code should either work correctly with multiple instances, or else clearly indicate that it cannot.

Comment: This may be beside the point, but using inheritance to model permission is really a poor design IMHO, because it can be better modeled by composing authorisation tokens. But that's a digression.

Comment: Thinking of classes as real-life "objects" is a absolutely terrible idea and will bite you in the ass in the form of unmanageable code. Classes are bundled functionality, a person, a battery or a tree all have absolutly nothing to do with functionality.

Comment: Jimbo Wales is an example of this on Wikipedia: He has his own permission set under the grouping of `Founder`. It is very unlikely it will ever apply to anyone else, but it is still easier to manage in the long term to have a named permission set, even though one person could have individual permissions set.

Answer (score 15):

It's silly to use this kind of class structure just to vary details which should obviously be settable fields on an instance. But that is particular to your example.

Making different `Person`s different classes is almost certainly a bad idea - you'd have to change your program and recompile every time a new Person enters your domain. However, that doesn't mean that inheriting from an existing class so that a different string is returned somewhere isn't sometimes useful.

The difference is how you expect the entities represented by that class to vary. People are almost always assumed to come and go, and almost every serious application dealing with users is expected to be able to add and remove users at run-time. But if you model things like different encryption algorithms, supporting a new one is probably a major change anyway, and it makes sense to invent a new class whose `myName()` method returns a different string (and whose `perform()` method presumably does something different).

Answer (score 12):

> Why would I create new classes when instances are enough?

In most cases, you wouldn't. Your example is really a good case where this behaviour doesn't add real value.

It also violates the [Open Closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), as the subclasses basically aren't an extension but modify the parent's inner workings. Moreover, the public constructor of the parent is now irritating in the subclasses and the API thus became less comprehensible.

However, somtimes, if you will only ever have one or two special configurations that are often used throughout the code, it is sometimes more convenient and less time consuming to just subclass a parent that has a complex constructor. In such special cases, I can see nothing wrong with such an approach. Let's call it *constructor currying* *j/k*

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the OCP paragraph. If a class is exposing a property setter to its descendants then- assuming it's following good design principles- the property should *not* be part of its inner workings

Comment: @BenAaronson As long as the behaviour of the property itself isn't altered, you don't violate OCP, but here they do. Of course you can use that Property in its inner workings. But you shouldn't alter existing behaviour! You should only extend behaviour, not change it with inheritance. Of course, there're exceptions to every rule.

Comment: So any use of virtual members is an OCP violation?

Comment: @Falcon There's no need to derive a new class just to avoid repetitive complex constructor calls. Just create factories for the common-cases and parameterize the small variations.

Comment: @BenAaronson I'd say having virtual members that have an actual implementation is such a violation. Abstract members, or say methods that do nothing, would be valid extension points. Basically, when you look at the code of a base class, you know that it's going to run as-is, instead of every non-final method being a candidate for being replaced with something entirely different. Or to put it differently: the ways by which an inheriting class can affect the behaviour of the base class will be explicit, and constrained to being "additive".

Comment: @millimoose: An extremely common pattern is for a parent class to have a virtual method and expect that derived classes which override it will call that method within the override, but also do some preprocessing and/or postprocessing.  Having one attachment point for the virtual method is easier than having separate attachment points for preprocessing and postprocessing [which would still need to have concrete implementations, even if they did nothing].

Comment: @supercat I won't argue "easier", but that doesn't necessarily mean it's "better" from a more rigorous standpoint. It might be common, but it seems like a violation of the OCP as the rule stands. (I'm not saying you're a bad coder if you don't follow all these principles slavishly, but they're backed by fairly solid reasoning.) And that pattern seems vaguely smelly / lazy to me – if the base class' implementation **must** be called, then the base class should ensure it does. If it's optional, perhaps the base class should instead be some sort of collaborator.

Comment: @millimoose: Outside of security-related contexts, base classes are not expected (and in general *cannot be expected*) to prevent the construction of illegitimate derived classes which do not abide by their inheritance contract.  The author of an abstract `DrawingContext` base class cannot be expected to prevent the author of a derived class from overriding the `FillPoly()` method so that it uses a robotic arm to feed a parrot.  There are cases where it's useful for a class to have a public-facing method which starts by calling a virtual method with an empty implementation...

Comment: ...then doing the base-class action, and then calling a second virtual method with another empty implementation.  The first derived class can then override the first of those methods with a sealed method which calls a new blank virtual method and then does its preprocessing, and the second with an override which does its postprocessing and calls another new blank virtual method.  Such an approach, however, requires adding two slots to the virtual method table for every layer of inheritance, and can get pretty ugly if there's any significant nesting.

Comment: Personally I think it would be nice for a language and framework to be able to mark a method in such a way that any override must be statically verifiable as chaining to the base method exactly once on any execution path which does not exit via exception, and chaining to it at most once in any case.  That would be cleaner than using separate hooks for pre- and post-processing methods, but I'm unaware of any language or framework that offers such a declaration.

Comment: Okay, but if you go with an argument based on "breaking the contract is technically possible anyway", then the only design principle you will ever need is throwing your hands up in disgust and going "*bleep* all y'all". And I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with these contrived hypotheticals where your approach is "useful". Clearly you're not going to lose sleep over violating the OCP in that case, and I'm not going to lose sleep over you doing so either. (And I can hardly propose my own solution for a problem that vague, especially expecting you to just contrive of another complication.)

Comment: @supercat – And I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish. It's not like I can go and get the OCP cancelled :D

Comment: @millimoose: A base class should ensure that a derived class *which abides by its inheritance contracts* will abide by the base class's public contracts.  In some cases it may be advantageous to add complexity in the base class to minimize the level of contractual obligations put onto a derived class; such efforts often make things more convenient for "leaf" classes [those with no descendants] at the expense of sub-derivable classes.

Answer (score 8):

If this is the extent of the practice, then I agree this is a bad practice.

If John and Karl have different behaviors, then things change a little bit. It could be that `person` has a method for `cleanRoom(Room room)` where it turns out that John is a great roommate and cleans very effectively, but Karl is not and doesn't clean the room very much.

In this case, it would make sense to have them be their own subclass with the behavior defined. There are better ways to achieve the same thing (for example, a `CleaningBehavior` class), but at least this way isn't a terrible violation of OO principles.

Comment: No different behavior, just different data. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In some cases you know there will only be a set number of instances and then it would kind of OK (although ugly in my opinion) to use this approach. It is better to use an enum if the language allows it.

Java example:

```
public enum Person
{
    KARL("Karl"),
    JOHN("John")

    private final String name;

    private Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A lot of people answered already. Thought I'd give my own personal perspective.

---

Once upon a time I worked on an app (and still do) that creates music.

The app had an abstract `Scale` class with several subclasses: `CMajor`, `DMinor`, etc. `Scale` looked something like so:

```
public abstract class Scale {
    protected Note[] notes;
    public Scale() {
        loadNotes();
    }
    // .. some other stuff ommited
    protected abstract void loadNotes(); /* subclasses put notes in the array
                                          in this method. */
}
```

The music generators worked with a specific `Scale` instance to generate music. The user would select a scale from a list, to generate music from.

One day, a cool idea came to my mind: why not allow the user to create his/her own scales? The user would select notes from a list, press a button, and a new scale would be added to the list available scales.

But I wasn't able to do this. That was because all the scales are already set at compile time - since they are expressed as classes. Then it hit me:

It's often intuitive to think in terms of 'superclasses and subclasses'. Almost everything can be expressed through this system: superclass `Person` and subclasses `John` and `Mary`; superclass `Car` and subclasses `Volvo` and `Mazda`; superclass `Missile` and subclasses `SpeedRocked`, `LandMine` and `TrippleExplodingThingy`.

It's very natural to think in this way, especially for the person relatively new to OO.

But we should always remember that ***classes are templates***, and ***objects are content poured into these templates***. You can pour whatever content you want into the template, creating countless possibilities.

**It's not the job of the subclass to fill the template. It's the job of the object.** The job of the subclass is to **add actual functionality**, or **expand the template**.

And that's why I should have created a concrete `Scale` class, with a `Note[]` field, and let *objects fill in this template*; possibly through the constructor or something. And eventually, so I did.

Every time you design a *template* in a class (e.g., an empty `Note[]` member that needs to be filled, or a `String name` field that needs to be assigned a value), remember that *it's the job of the objects of this class to fill in the template* (or possibly those creating these objects). Subclasses are meant to add functionality, not to fill in templates.

---

You might be tempted to create a "superclass `Person`, subclasses `John` and `Mary`" kind of system, like you did, because you like the formality this gets you.

This way, you can just say `Person p = new Mary()`, instead of `Person p = new Person("Mary", 57, Sex.FEMALE)`. It makes things more organized, and more structured. But as we said, creating a new class for every combination of data isn't good approach, since it bloats the code for nothing and limits you in terms of runtime abilities.

So here's a solution: use a basic factory, might even be a static one. Like so:

```
public final class PersonFactory {
    private PersonFactory() { }

    public static Person createJohn(){
        return new Person("John", 40, Sex.MALE);
    }

    public static Person createMary(){
        return new Person("Mary", 57, Sex.FEMALE);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way, you can easily use the 'presets' the 'come with the program', like so: `Person mary = PersonFactory.createMary()`, but you also reserve the right to design new persons dynamically, for example in the case that you want to allow the user to do so. E.g.:

```
// .. requesting the user for input ..
String name = // user input
int age = // user input
Sex sex = // user input, interpreted
Person newPerson = new Person(name, age, sex);
```

Or even better: do something like so:

```
public final class PersonFactory {
    private PersonFactory() { }

    private static Map<String, Person> persons = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, PersonData> personBlueprints = new HashMap<>();

    public static void addPerson(Person person){
        persons.put(person.getName(), person);
    }

    public static Person getPerson(String name){
        return persons.get(name);
    }

    public static Person createPerson(String blueprintName){
        PersonData data = personBlueprints.get(blueprintName);
        return new Person(data.name, data.age, data.sex);
    }

    // .. or, alternative to the last method
    public static Person createPerson(String personName){
        Person blueprint = persons.get(personName);
        return new Person(blueprint.getName(), blueprint.getAge(), blueprint.getSex());
    }

}

public class PersonData {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public Sex sex;

    public PersonData(String name, int age, Sex sex){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
```

I got carried away. I think you get the idea.

---

**Subclasses are not meant to fill in the templates set by their superclasses. Subclasses are meant to *add functionality*. *Object* are meant to fill in the templates, that's what they're for.**

You shouldn't be creating a new class for every possible combination of data. (Just like I shouldn't have created a new `Scale` subclass for every possible combination of `Note`s).

Her'es a guideline: whenever you create a new subclass, consider if it adds any new functionality that doesn't exist in the superclass. **If the answer to that question is "no", than you might be trying to 'fill in the template' of the superclass, in which case just create an object.** (And possibly a Factory with 'presets', to make life easier).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is an excellent example, thank you very much.

Comment: @SoMoS Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

This is an exception to the 'should be instances' here - although slightly extreme.

If you wanted the *compiler* to enforce permissions to access methods based on whether it is Karl or John (in this example) rather than ask the method implementation to check for which instance has been passed then you might use different classes. By enforcing different classes rather than instantiation then you make differentiation checks between 'Karl' and 'John' possible at compile time rather than run time and this *might* be useful - particularly in a security context where the compiler may be more trusted than run-time code checks of (for example) external libraries.

Answer (score 2):

It's considered a [bad practice to have duplicated code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

This is at least partially because [lines of codes and therefore size of codebase correlates to maintenance costs and defects](http://www.mayerdan.com/ruby/2012/11/11/bugs-per-line-of-code-ratio/).

Here's the relevant common sense logic to me on this particular topic :

1) If I were to need to change this, how many places would I need to visit? Less is better here.

2) Is there a reason why it is done this way?  In your example - there couldn't be - but in some examples there might be some kind of reason for doing this.  One I can think of off the top of my head is in some frameworks like early Grails where inheritance didn't necessarily play nicely with some of the plugins for GORM. Few and far between.

3) Is it cleaner and easier to understand this way?  Again, it isn't in your example - but there are some inheritance patterns that may be more of a stretch where separated classes is actually easier to maintain (certain usages of the command or strategy patterns come to mind).

Comment: whether it's bad or not is not set in stone. There are for example scenarios where the extra overhead of object creation and method calls can be so detrimental for performance that the application no longer meets specifications.

Comment: See point #2.  Sure there's reasons why, occasionally. That's why you need to ask before gutting out someone's code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a use case: forming a reference to a function or method as a regular object.

You can see this in Java GUI code a lot:

```
ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

The compiler helps you here by creating a new anonymous subclass.